# I can't use the bios on an external monitor

Tags: bios, external-display

I have Samsung npc300esc and my screen is broken. I have connected it to a external monitor but the bios doesn't connect to it. I tried all FN+FKEY but nothing happen.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried different display cables, downloading the correct driver for the monitor, and of course making sure your system is up to date with BIOS, drivers etc....?

FYI there is no real trouble shooting or technical information, please explain what else you have done to resolve this and explain how you know it's the BIOS that isn't picking it up. This is a help forum site but we're here to help, not do it/fix if for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try fn+ F4 button on your lap (settings button for displaying in external display).[image]